# How does one update the version of Hibernate that SCDF uses?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, cockroachdb

I am trying to get Spring Cloud DataFlow to work with CockroachDB as its persistence layer.

The problem that I have is that CockroachDB does not support the PostgreSQL Large Object server-side functions (e.g. lo_create) which the default postgreSQL dialect for Hibernate employs when registering apps in SCDF.

As of [Hibernate ORM 5.4.19](https://in.relation.to/2020/07/27/hibernate-orm-5419-final-release/) a new dialect specifically for CockroachDB is now supported. However, the version of Hibernate SCDF uses is too outdated and doesn't contain this dialect.

My problem now is how do I inject the newer version of Hibernate into SCDF? I tried launching SCDF via a Spring Boot app that overrides the version of Hibernate - but failed at this miserably and from what I can glean from the other questions, is not really supported anymore anyways (?)

Answer (score 1):

SCDF 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT uses version 5.4.22.Final of Hibernate which supports the CockroachDB201Dialect

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying 2.7.x snapshots(or 2.7.0-M2 sometime next week) as that is on latest framework/boot versions which pulls hibernate 5.4.21. 2.6.x line will get updates with a next maintenance release.

Custom builds are a bit pain to handle and we would not recommend changing anything core stuff what's directly coming from a framework deps.

Comment: I *am* using 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT. The version of hibernate used there is 5.4.18.Final